# titlesec: left margin alignment of run-in custom headers

Tags: titlesec

I've used `titlesec` to define headers in my custom `.sty` file. See the code at the end of this post, and especially the `runin` shape spec for `paragraph`. For various reasons, I want numbered level 4 headers with text starting in the same line, so `runin` seems the way to go. However, the code I've written causes level 4 headers to jut into the left margin, rather than aligning nicely with everything else:

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong here? How can I ensure that run-in headers are left-aligned?

Relevant portion of `.sty` file

```
\RequirePackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\titleformat
{\section}               % command
[hang]                   % shape
{\Large\bfseries}        % format   
{\thesection}            % label
{1em}                    % sep
{}                       % before-code
[]                       % after-code

\titlespacing*           % star ensures \noindent on the following paragraph
{\section}               % command
{}                       % left
{2ex}                    % before-sep
{1ex}                    % after-sep

\titleformat
{\subsection}            % command
[hang]                   % shape
{\large\bfseries}        % format   
{\thesubsection}         % label
{1em}                    % sep
{}                       % before-code
[]                       % after-code

\titleformat
{\subsubsection}         % command
[hang]                   % shape
{\normalsize\itshape}    % format   
{\thesubsubsection}      % label
{1em}                    % sep
{}                       % before-code
[]                       % after-code

\titleformat
{\paragraph}             % command
[run]                    % shape
{\normalsize\itshape}    % format   
{\theparagraph}          % label
{1em}                    % sep
{}                       % before-code
[]                       % after-code
```

Comment: You have `run` instead of `runin`; you miss a dimension in `\titlespacing` (the empty argument should be `0pt` or whatever). If I fix these problems, I get the expected results; otherwise I get errors. A minimal example is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed everything partly following egreg's suggestion. The solution consists of defining a `\titlespacing` function for `\paragraph` and then letting `\parindent` be the value of the `left` argument.

```
[![\titleformat
{\paragraph}             % command
\[run\]                    % shape
{\normalsize\itshape}    % format   
{\theparagraph}          % label
{1em}                    % sep
{}                       % before-code
\[\]                       % after-code

\titlespacing
{\paragraph}             % command
{\parindent}             % left
{2ex}                    % before-sep
{3ex}                    % after-sep
```

Here is the result: compare to the one I had yesterday.

[image: problem solved!]